# ESXi alerts to consolidate but there were no snapshots taken

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, snapshot

I recently came a cross a disk failure on our server and got the disk replaced. Due to this disk failure there were certain issues which raised and now its going up and down. What my problem is that, on our ESXi we've set-up **ghettoVCB** script to backup all our VM's. Very recently due this disk degrade, few of our VM's shows an error as `Configuration Issues – Virtual Machine disks consolidation is needed`.

[image]

When I had a look into the snapshot manager of those VM's, I did not find any snapshots. So, I assume this is because of the back scrip we use and I'm wondering how to fix this without loosing any of the DATA(s) or the VM.

If anyone can guide me how to fix this.. will be a great help.

## Update

One of VM cannot be consolidated as it gives below error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tied to your backup solution. VMware details the [process here.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003638)

It's harmless.

All you need to do is select the "Consolidate" option from the VM's snapshot menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've actually gone through that KB and I didn't do anything as the backup was broken. But as per [**this question**](http://serverfault.com/questions/184262/question-about-consolidate-helper-0), I'm also seeing some locked file & also few vmdk files named delta. Will that be an issue if I do consolidation or is it better to do a recent backup of the VM's folder itself before consolidating.

Comment: Just run the consolidation. It's a remnant of your backup process.

Comment: I tried one VM and it worked. Took a long time due to the size of the VM I guess, but it did the work.

Comment: Hi! As you said it was consolidating the other virtual machines perfectly except for one. Also, I do remember that I installed certain apps on that machine after this message appears.. what I can I do to over come this?

Comment: You said it's harmless but my vm hangs for about a minute when I use it...